# Common audio signal voltage range on Line out connector

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, audio, signal, output

What is typical audio signal voltage range on Line out connector of consumer electronic devices? (Vmin/Vmax) 
I need specify *Input voltage range* to calculate op-amp. `Vin pk-pk`, `Vin Midpoint`, or `Vin Min`, `Vin Max` I know the line level depends on the device type, but in general?

Comment: Unable to google? [Line Level -- Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level). If you already read it, then you should have expanded your question.

Comment: +1 for @jonk ....but many consumer products actually have a headphone out jack, which is not quite the same ....here you may find 1-100 mW or more into 32-600 Ohms.

Comment: @JackCreasey Output power for headphones varies a bit from device to device. I remember seeing a table with commonly owned cell phones, for example. But delivered into the usual \$32\:\Omega\$ headphone, it's typically around \$4-5\:\text{mW}\$ if I can trust the few sources I read. This suggests a peak of about \$500\:\text{mV}\$, to me. Obviously, there are different amplifiers with different target headphone impedances, too. So one has to decide the target source, I suppose, if considering headphone jacks as opposed to line out connectors.

Comment: Not for headphone out, I'm talking only about _Line out_ voltage. What is `Vin Midpoint`voltage?

Comment: An audio input should be AC-coupled to prevent any DC component from the input signal from upsetting the operating point of the input stage, so Vin Midpoint should be  irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Usually consumer line outputs are nominal -10dBV (about .316V RMS).

But many devices put out less than this, for example a Mac Pro 5,1 line out puts out about 180mV RMS (250mVp) with a sinusoidal input of -20dBFS and maxes out at about 2V RMS (2.8Vp) with an input of 0dBFS. These are open-circuit measurements I have taken myself.

So to be safe you should design for -10dBV nominal (max headroom would be 20dB above that so +10dBV [3.16V RMS]). That way most consumer devices won't clip your input.

But you should also choose a device you think might be used with your design frequently and measure it so you know for sure what you are expecting. Like a headphone jack on an iphone or something.